# Find Two Linearly Independent Vectors as the Basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $(1,0,1,1)$ and $(0,1,1,-1)$ are two vectors in the basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, find the other two vectors in the basis.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried, and what confuses you or where you're stuck.

Comment: There is not "the basis" but **a basis**, and there are no "the other two vectors " but **some other two vectors ...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the two given vectors as the first two rows of a upper triangular $4\times 4$ matrix. Complete the matrix in order to have a determinant different from $0$. 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \ast \end{bmatrix}$$

One way to do it is by taking $(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(1,1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,1,0)$ just by displacing the zero, so every vector has a zero at another position in the vector. 
Now you just need to check that this forms a base (by using the determinant or other techniques for example). Hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) is a systematic method that not only guarantees linear independence, but furthermore orthogonal vectors.

Comment: @z For that you need to have an inner product space, which isn't given here. And no: we cannot assume the standard, Euclidean inner product. This is clearly a beginners question.